# Post strings to WCF service endpoint with jQuery.ajax (500)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, wcf, web-services

This problem has been presented in a number of posts in similar ways without a viable solution to mine.

My service endpoint in `ManagerDiscountService` looks like:

```
[ServiceBehavior]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Cart")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ManagerDiscountService : CartService

    [OperationContract]
    // also tried [WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    // also tried [WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, Method="POST")]
    public MyObject ToggleMode(string userId, string pwd, string domain)
```

web.config:

```
<service name="Cart.ManagerDiscountService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Item.ItemAspNetAjaxBehavior"
     binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsSecureHttp" 
     contract="Cart.ManagerDiscountService" />
</service>
<!-- tried adding a similar wsHttp binding since the POST is not SSL, no luck -->
```

I'm trying to post `userId`, `pwd` and `domain` to this endpoint, but all I see are 500's. *Why doesn't this method of posting work*? When I debug in Chrome, `error` is always the next execution in `$.ajax`:

```
params = { "userId": "user", "pwd": "password", "domain": "mydomain" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/Cart/ManagerDiscountService.svc/ToggleMode",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params, null, null),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

::sigh:: this was corrected by replacing the `wsSecureHttp` binding with `wsHttp`

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Item.ItemAspNetAjaxBehavior"
 binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" 
 contract="Cart.ManagerDiscountService" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a uri template i guess.
I have edited your code Here:

`[OperationContract]

[WebGet(UriTemplate="ToggleMode?userId={userId}&pwd={pwd}&domain="{domain}",                                                                             ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]`

where method will look like:
`MyObject ToggleMode(string userId, string pwd, string domain);`

Also, your ajax call url will look like:
`url: "/Ajax/Cart/ManagerDiscountService.svc/ToggleMode?userId=uid&pwd=pwd&domain=domain",`
and then you dont need to set the 'data' in your ajax call...see if this works.

Comment: This is a login feature, so I need it to be `POST`

Answer (score 0):

Try using code as follows:

```
params = { "userId": "user", "pwd": "password", "domain": "mydomain" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/Cart/ManagerDiscountService.svc/ToggleMode",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

also for what you are passing extra two null parameters to the contract.

Comment: The null parameters are to handle some problems we saw in IE8. I've also tried without the null parameters with no luck.